# Installation of rlang fails in GitHub action when trying to install the pkgdown dev version with pak

Tags: r, github-actions, rlang, pkgdown

I am using the folowing YAML to [run a GitHub action](https://github.com/nflverse/nflplotR/blob/main/.github/workflows/pkgdown.yaml) that should build and deploy a pkgdown website.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
    tags: ['*']
  workflow_dispatch:

name: pkgdown

jobs:
  pkgdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1
        with:
          extra-packages: >
            r-lib/pkgdown
          needs: website

      - name: Deploy package
        run: |
          git config --local user.name "$GITHUB_ACTOR"
          git config --local user.email "$GITHUB_ACTOR@users.noreply.github.com"
          Rscript -e 'pkgdown::deploy_to_branch(new_process = FALSE)'
```

This action worked well and the last time was 8 days ago. But since a few days it is failing in the installation stage of dependencies. I will provide a screenshot of the relevant console output as well as the complete log of the stage where it is failing.

[screenshot of GitHub action console output (complete log below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhHTj.png)

```
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5221045Z ##[group]Run r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5221706Z with:
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5222210Z   extra-packages: r-lib/pkgdown

2021-10-13T09:21:01.5222743Z   needs: website
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5223213Z   cache-version: 1
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5223636Z env:
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5225057Z   GITHUB_PAT: ***
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5225618Z   R_LIBS_USER: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5226092Z   TZ: UTC
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5226528Z   _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5226986Z   NOT_CRAN: true
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5227834Z   RSPM: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5228677Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5277479Z ##[group]Run cat("::group::Install pak\n")
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5278120Z [36;1mcat("::group::Install pak\n")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5278698Z [36;1moptions(pak.no_extra_messages = TRUE)[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5279581Z [36;1minstall.packages("pak", repos = "https://r-lib.github.io/p/pak/dev/")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5280677Z [36;1msaveRDS(pak::pkg_deps("local::.", dependencies = TRUE), ".github/r-depends.rds")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5299809Z shell: /usr/local/bin/Rscript {0}
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5300501Z env:
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5301485Z   GITHUB_PAT: ***
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5302038Z   R_LIBS_USER: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5302534Z   TZ: UTC
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5302954Z   _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5303416Z   NOT_CRAN: true
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5304251Z   RSPM: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest
2021-10-13T09:21:01.5305093Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:01.7735915Z ##[group]Install pak
2021-10-13T09:21:01.7778316Z Installing package into ‘/home/runner/work/_temp/Library’
2021-10-13T09:21:01.7779380Z (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
2021-10-13T09:21:02.0804887Z trying URL 'https://r-lib.github.io/p/pak/dev/src/contrib/pak_0.1.2.9001_R4-1_x86_64-pc-linux-musl.tar.gz'
2021-10-13T09:21:02.1484219Z Content type 'application/gzip' length 10010856 bytes (9.5 MB)
2021-10-13T09:21:02.2461423Z ==================================================
2021-10-13T09:21:02.2462749Z downloaded 9.5 MB
2021-10-13T09:21:02.2463250Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:03.8881352Z * installing *binary* package ‘pak’ ...
2021-10-13T09:21:03.9529849Z * DONE (pak)
2021-10-13T09:21:03.9925933Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:03.9927322Z The downloaded source packages are in
2021-10-13T09:21:03.9929669Z    ‘/tmp/RtmpoB9BkI/downloaded_packages’
2021-10-13T09:21:05.9009638Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:06.6801986Z ✔ Updated metadata database: 3.17 MB in 7 files.
2021-10-13T09:21:06.6813423Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:06.6823418Z ℹ Updating metadata database
2021-10-13T09:21:16.1791621Z ✔ Updating metadata database ... done
2021-10-13T09:21:16.1792521Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3533703Z ##[group]Run cat("::set-output name=os-version::", sessionInfo()$running, "\n", sep = "")
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3534607Z [36;1mcat("::set-output name=os-version::", sessionInfo()$running, "\n", sep = "")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3535399Z [36;1mcat("::set-output name=r-version::", R.Version()$version.string, "\n", sep = "")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3536045Z [36;1mcat("::endgroup::\n")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3546457Z shell: /usr/local/bin/Rscript {0}
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3547071Z env:
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3548345Z   GITHUB_PAT: ***
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3549677Z   R_LIBS_USER: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3550187Z   TZ: UTC
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3550733Z   _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3551194Z   NOT_CRAN: true
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3552035Z   RSPM: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest
2021-10-13T09:21:17.3552883Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:17.5570628Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6419006Z ##[group]Run actions/cache@v2
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6419443Z with:
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6419999Z   path: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library/*
!/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/pak

2021-10-13T09:21:17.6421487Z   key: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS-R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)-1-424d32e8fa86286fdc1bade6169decf325942acc98cf5b835a12d6bd44cb0907
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6422831Z   restore-keys: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS-R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)-1-
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6423433Z env:
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6424767Z   GITHUB_PAT: ***
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6425238Z   R_LIBS_USER: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6425661Z   TZ: UTC
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6426022Z   _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6426420Z   NOT_CRAN: true
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6427158Z   RSPM: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest
2021-10-13T09:21:17.6427881Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:19.1120572Z Received 58720256 of 98015724 (59.9%), 55.9 MBs/sec
2021-10-13T09:21:19.4330618Z Received 98015724 of 98015724 (100.0%), 70.7 MBs/sec
2021-10-13T09:21:19.4331918Z Cache Size: ~93 MB (98015724 B)
2021-10-13T09:21:19.4364534Z [command]/usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/46465d08-9d78-40c9-8a32-c088d62ba903/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/nflplotR/nflplotR
2021-10-13T09:21:20.2540726Z Cache restored successfully
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3146223Z Cache restored from key: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS-R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)-1-b3a639120b490509af7d824edaa680dd8b9288a21078a01f03e3b354f56bb911
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3289712Z ##[group]Run cat("::group::Install dependencies\n")
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3290478Z [36;1mcat("::group::Install dependencies\n")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3291115Z [36;1moptions(pak.no_extra_messages = TRUE)[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3291807Z [36;1mlocal_deps <- pak::local_dev_deps(dependencies = "all")[["ref"]][0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3292612Z [36;1mneeds <- sprintf("Config/Needs/%s", strsplit("website", "[[:space:],]+")[[1]])[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3293558Z [36;1mneeds_deps <- pak::local_dev_deps(dependencies = needs)[["ref"]][0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3294353Z [36;1mneeds_only_deps <- setdiff(needs_deps, local_deps)[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3295041Z [36;1mextra_deps <- strsplit("r-lib/pkgdown[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3295566Z [36;1m", "[[:space:],]+")[[1]][0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3296077Z [36;1mif (Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Linux") {[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3296753Z [36;1m  pak::local_system_requirements(execute = TRUE)[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3297439Z [36;1m  for (dep in c(needs_only_deps, extra_deps)) {[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3298156Z [36;1m    pak::pkg_system_requirements(dep, execute = TRUE)[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3298717Z [36;1m  }[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3299075Z [36;1m}[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3300031Z [36;1mpak::pkg_install(c(local_deps, needs_only_deps, extra_deps, "sessioninfo"))[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3300643Z [36;1mcat("::endgroup::\n")[0m
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3311214Z shell: /usr/local/bin/Rscript {0}
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3311639Z env:
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3312974Z   GITHUB_PAT: ***
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3313459Z   R_LIBS_USER: /home/runner/work/_temp/Library
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3313898Z   TZ: UTC
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3314287Z   _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3314683Z   NOT_CRAN: true
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3315436Z   RSPM: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest
2021-10-13T09:21:20.3316222Z ##[endgroup]
2021-10-13T09:21:20.5290600Z ##[group]Install dependencies
2021-10-13T09:21:22.8022442Z ℹ Loading metadata database
2021-10-13T09:21:25.1845907Z ✔ Loading metadata database ... done
2021-10-13T09:21:25.1860369Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:27.6663364Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:28.4891094Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:29.0651416Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y make`
2021-10-13T09:21:29.6121703Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:37.5303912Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libicu-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:38.1033026Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:38.6831428Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:39.2349019Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick`
2021-10-13T09:21:39.8102272Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:44.1291794Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y gsfonts`
2021-10-13T09:21:48.7833892Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev`
2021-10-13T09:21:49.3385954Z ℹ Executing `sudo apt-get install -y pandoc`
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0712914Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0726607Z ##[error]Error: <callr_remote_error: Cannot install packages:
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0742655Z * r-lib/pkgdown: Can't install dependency r-lib/rlang
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0743647Z * r-lib/rlang: Conflicts with rlang>
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0744192Z  in process 11033 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0744752Z -->
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0745340Z <simpleError: Cannot install packages:
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0746301Z * r-lib/pkgdown: Can't install dependency r-lib/rlang
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0747184Z * r-lib/rlang: Conflicts with rlang>
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0809388Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0810068Z  Stack trace:
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0810368Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0810794Z  12. (function (...)  ...
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0811757Z  13. base:::withCallingHandlers(cli_message = function(msg) { ...
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0812680Z  14. get("pkg_install_make_plan", asNamespace("pak"))(...)
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0813331Z  15. prop$stop_for_solution_error()
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0813954Z  16. private$plan$stop_for_solve_error()
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0815336Z  17. pkgdepends:::pkgplan_stop_for_solve_error(self, private)
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0816235Z  18. base:::stop("Cannot install packages:\n", msg, call. = FALSE)
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0817082Z  19. base:::.handleSimpleError(function (e)  ...
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0817779Z  20. h(simpleError(msg, call))
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0818574Z  21. base:::stop(e)
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0819023Z  22. (function (e)  ...
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0819312Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0819870Z  x Cannot install packages:
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0821046Z * r-lib/pkgdown: Can't install dependency r-lib/rlang
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0821853Z * r-lib/rlang: Conflicts with rlang 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0822187Z 
2021-10-13T09:21:59.0822577Z Execution halted
2021-10-13T09:21:59.1051870Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

While I was trying to fix this I found that at least one other package (httr2) is having  [the exact same problem](https://github.com/r-lib/httr2/actions/workflows/pkgdown.yaml).

I think this might be related to [a recent change](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/commit/3ba19df8b234ca328dfd703085d2499a6790bd29) of the version number of the current rlang development version but I have absolutely no idea why or how it can be fixed. Since I am not sure about the ultimate source of the problem I didn't create a GitHub issue and am instead trying my luck here.

My current workaround is building and deploying the website from my local machine but I feel like this should be investigated.

Comment: I have been asked to file an issue in the r-lib/pak repo so this will be tracked on GitHub now. https://github.com/r-lib/pak/issues/322